# C# get assembly based on namespace

Tags: c#

O've seen "get namespace from assembly" -- but how do you know what assembly the namespace is in? I'm trying to get all types of a namespace, and to do that I need to know the assembly, but the assembly isn't always just Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly, I need to get a list of all assemblies with a particular namespace in them.

How can I do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't know beforehand what namespaces are defined in an assembly (not directly; in order to do that you need a decompiler and then a file parser to check their namespaces).

The thing you could do is load all the assemblies you want `System.Reflection.Assembly Load(pathToAssembly)` and then go through their `.DefinedTypes()` to filter the namespaces you want.

Loading all the assemblies for your current project:

```
List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(assemblyFolder, "*.dll"))
{
    assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(path));
}
```

Comment: I don't have a pathToAssembly, I'm just using unity, how can I just get all active assembies and select the one that has the namespace I want?

Comment: I updated my answer with loading all assemblies for the current running project

Comment: Im using unity though, I don't think there is an assemblyFolder, especially when I build the application, can this be done without reference to a directory?

Comment: You can do it like this then `var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();` just that in this case the list will also contain stuff like system DLLs (e.g. System.Runtime / System.IO)

Comment: @bluejayke Did it do for you?